# Overwrite Permissions for all channels in a discord server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a moderation discord bot with a mute command. The mute command works in the channel that you send the command in but it doesn't work in all of the other channels. I've tried to have it go over all channels using forEach() but that doesn't seem to work. I've looked through this and tried the other solutions but its still not working. Here is the code, I hope you can help.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const ms = require('ms')

module.exports = {
    name: "mute",
    aliases: [],
    category: "moderation",
    run: async(bot, message, args) => {
        let toMute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]));
        if(!toMute) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find the user.");
        if(toMute.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Can't mute them")
        let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(muteRole => muteRole.name === "Muted");


//This is where the problem starts
        if(!muteRole){
            muteRole = await message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: "Muted", color: 0x000000, permissions: [] } })
            message.guild.channels.cache.each(async (channel) => {
                await channel.overwritePermissions(muteRole, {
                    "SEND_MESSAGES": false, 
                    "ADD_REACTIONS": false,
                    "TALK": false
                    });

            });
        }

        let muteTime = args[1];
        if(!muteTime) return message.reply("Please Specify a time.");


        await(toMute.roles.add(muteRole));
        const mEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Muted")
        .addFields({ name: "Member", value: toMute, inline: false },
        { name: "Time", value: muteTime })
        .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send(mEmbed)

        setTimeout(function() {
            toMute.roles.remove(muteRole);
            message.channel.send(`<@${toMute.id}> has been unmuted`);
        }, ms(muteTime)) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the overwritePermissions() to updateOverwrite() and it seemed to work. Here is the code:

```js
        if(!muteRole){
            muteRole = await message.guild.roles.create({
                data: {
                    name: "Muted",
                    color: "#000000",
                    permissions: [],
                },
            });
            message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
                await channel.updateOverwrite(muteRole, {
                    SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                    SPEAK: false,
                    ADD_REACTIONS: false
                })
            });
        }
```

I also organized the code to make it easier to see.